# Ошибка hello.go:1:1: illegal character U+FEFF

Tags: golang, windows

Действую по инструкции при проверке установки на Windows XP (до этого все делал на Linux). Скачиваю msi, устанавливаю его, создаю текстовый файл, копирую туда содержимое с Go-сайта

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Запускаю командой go run hello.go, в итоге вижу сообщение

> `hello.go:1:1: illegal character U+FEFF`

Что не так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

U+FEFF это код BOM (Byte-Order-Mark), специальной отметки в начале файла в одной из кодировок Unicode. BOM необходим для определения вида 16-битной кодировки Unicode (UTF-16BE или UTF-16LE). Для распространенной кодировки UTF-8 BOM не применяется. Проблема в том, что стандарт Unicode явно не запрещает ставить BOM в начале текста в UTF-8 текстовыми редакторами. Замечено, что некоторые текстовые редакторы в Windows ставят BOM в UTF-8. Ваш транслятор Go, наоборот, полагает, что этот код здесь лишний, очень удивляется и диагностирует ошибку.

Решения:

1. Если ваш код содержит только символы Latin-1, сохраняйте в любой ASCII кодировке, коды Latin-1 совпадают с кодами UTF-8.
2. Если планируется использовать символы вне набора Latin-1, советую подыскать нормальный Unicode-редактор, который не ставит ненужный BOM в начало текста в UTF-8.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что это проблема винды. По-моему скорее виноват копулятор Go, который может в Уникод, но про BOM ничего не знает (и это в 2012 году!)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка появляется, если сохранить документ как UTF-8. Вставьте код в блокнот и сохраните как ANSI, а потом перезапустите - все будет ок.